# the order of translate and scale for zoom and pan

Tags: opengl

first thing I want to do is translating to the center of the screen and draw all of the objects from there. 
then I would like  to apply tranlsate for panning and scale for zoom.  I want to zoom relative to a center point ! so how should be the order of them so that it works ?

```
glTranslatef(width/2, height/2, 0); 
gltranslate(centerX,centerY); // go to center point
glscale(zoom);
glTranslatef(offset.x/zoom, offset.y/zoom, offset.z/zoom); // pan
```

I tried the above order but it doesn't go to the center point and it always zoom relative to (0,0).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are drawing a square with both x and y between 0,1.

first you have to translate to the point the scaled object should be:

```
glTranslate3f(centerX,centerY,0);
glScale(zoom);
glTranslatef(-0.5f, -0.5f,0); // to the middle
draw stuff
```

opengl executes the transformations in reverse order since it's a pipeline.
reading the above sequence in the bottom-up direction will give the key.